# How to parse a JSON response

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

This is my json response:

```
{  
   "wk_time":{  
      "user":{  
         "id":11,
         "name":"geetha adhi"
      },
      "startday":"2015-08-09",
      "status":"New",
      "total":38.23,
      "time_entries":[  
         {  
            "id":246,
            "project":{  
               "id":4,
               "name":"Vitals"
            },
            "issue":{  
               "id":22
            },
            "user":{  
               "id":11,
               "name":"geetha adhi"
            },
            "activity":{  
               "id":8,
               "name":"Design"
            },
            "hours":7.0,
            "comments":"test",
            "spent_on":"2015-08-09",
            "custom_fields":[  
               {  
                  "id":9,
                  "name":"Test"
               },
               {  
                  "id":10,
                  "name":"test2"
               }
            ]
         },
         {  
            "id":287,
            "project":{  
               "id":4,
               "name":"Vitals"
            },
            "issue":{  
               "id":22
            },
            "user":{  
               "id":11,
               "name":"geetha adhi"
            },
            "activity":{  
               "id":8,
               "name":"Design"
            },
            "hours":5.0,
            "comments":"test",
            "spent_on":"2015-08-10",
            "custom_fields":[  
               {  
                  "id":9,
                  "name":"Test"
               },
               {  
                  "id":10,
                  "name":"test2"
               }
            ]
         },
         {  
            "id":288,
            "project":{  
               "id":4,
               "name":"Vitals"
            },
            "issue":{  
               "id":22
            },
            "user":{  
               "id":11,
               "name":"geetha adhi"
            },
            "activity":{  
               "id":8,
               "name":"Design"
            },
            "hours":5.0,
            "comments":"test",
            "spent_on":"2015-08-11",
            "custom_fields":[  
               {  
                  "id":9,
                  "name":"Test"
               },
               {  
                  "id":10,
                  "name":"test2"
               }
            ]
         },
         {  
            "id":289,
            "project":{  
               "id":4,
               "name":"Vitals"
            },
            "issue":{  
               "id":22
            },
            "user":{  
               "id":11,
               "name":"geetha adhi"
            },
            "activity":{  
               "id":8,
               "name":"Design"
            },
            "hours":5.0,
            "comments":"test",
            "spent_on":"2015-08-12",
            "custom_fields":[  
               {  
                  "id":9,
                  "name":"Test"
               },
               {  
                  "id":10,
                  "name":"test2"
               }
            ]
         },
         {  
            "id":291,
            "project":{  
               "id":4,
               "name":"Vitals"
            },
            "issue":{  
               "id":22
            },
            "user":{  
               "id":11,
               "name":"geetha adhi"
            },
            "activity":{  
               "id":8,
               "name":"Design"
            },
            "hours":5.0,
            "comments":"test",
            "spent_on":"2015-08-14",
            "custom_fields":[  
               {  
                  "id":9,
                  "name":"Test"
               },
               {  
                  "id":10,
                  "name":"test2"
               }
            ]
         },
         {  
            "id":292,
            "project":{  
               "id":4,
               "name":"Vitals"
            },
            "issue":{  
               "id":22
            },
            "user":{  
               "id":11,
               "name":"geetha adhi"
            },
            "activity":{  
               "id":8,
               "name":"Design"
            },
            "hours":5.0,
            "comments":"test",
            "spent_on":"2015-08-15",
            "custom_fields":[  
               {  
                  "id":9,
                  "name":"Test"
               },
               {  
                  "id":10,
                  "name":"test2"
               }
            ]
         },
         {  
            "id":492,
            "project":{  
               "id":4,
               "name":"Vitals"
            },
            "issue":{  
               "id":22
            },
            "user":{  
               "id":11,
               "name":"geetha adhi"
            },
            "activity":{  
               "id":9,
               "name":"Development"
            },
            "hours":6.23,
            "comments":"ttest",
            "spent_on":"2015-08-09",
            "custom_fields":[  
               {  
                  "id":9,
                  "name":"Test"
               },
               {  
                  "id":10,
                  "name":"test2"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

My piece of code:

```
NSURLRequest * urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:response url]];
NSError * error = nil;
NSURLResponse * response = nil;
NSData * jsonSource = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest returningResponse:&response error:&error];
NSLog(@" %@",jsonSource);
id jsonObjects = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: jsonSource options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];

if ([jsonObjects objectForKey:@"wk_time"] != [NSNull null]) {
    NSArray *itemArray = [jsonObjects objectForKey:@"wk_time"];
    NSLog(@" %@",itemArray);
}
```

I have done this much so far. I wish to get project name, activity name. How to get this?

Comment: [[[[[DictJsonName objectForKey:@"wk_time"] objectForKey:@"time_entries"] objectAtIndex:changeNumber] objectForKey:@"project"] objectForKey:@"name"]
                
                [[[[[DictJsonName objectForKey:@"wk_time"] objectForKey:@"time_entries"] objectAtIndex:changeNumber] objectForKey:@"activity"] objectForKey:@"name"]

Comment: catherine show me the url which you get the reponse using that url.Please show me that

Comment: I will help you now if you show me the url for getting response.

Comment: @user3182143 yeah thanks for your response that url runs in my local...how could you use that url any idea ...

Comment: Why i am asking the URL is,it is very easy for showing output response code step by step through my code.Also you can easily understand what i did.

Comment: Can you show me that url?

Comment: http://192.168.0.8/redmine/wktime/edit.json?startday=2015-08-09&user_id=11&key=828ea7fa548b09098f2acd6c9334411c7a2cdac4 this is my url...

Comment: @user3182143 do u see the url..

Comment: I could not see any URL above in your question.The URL is like http://www........

Comment: I want you to show the  url from NSURLRequest * urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL    URLWithString:response url]];

Comment: i mentioned in comment....starts with 192....that's why i said it runs in my local machine you can't see...

Comment: Okey.Now I will help you.

Comment: @user3182143 that is the response url i am using my response url is http://192.168.0.8/redmine/wktime/edit.json?startday=2015-08-09&user_id=11&key=828ea7fa548b09098f2acd6c9334411c7a2cdac4

Comment: @RamVinayYadav tahnks bro..it works fine....

Comment: Catherine see my answer it is so helpful for you.It works fine.

Comment: Tell me once it works out.

Comment: Kindly tick my answer.The reason why because it is helpful for other stack overflow viewers when they see your question generally.

Comment: @RamVinayYadav  bro if my response like this....{"wk_time":{"user":{"id":11,"name":"geetha adhi"},"startday":"2015-11-29","time_entries":[]} then if i put  like this [[[[[DictJsonName objectForKey:@"wk_time"] objectForKey:@"time_entries"] objectAtIndex:changeNumber] objectForKey:@"project"] objectForKey:@"name"]  it shows the error how to avoid this error bro...

Comment: @ catherine007  in this responce if u want geeta adhi.  Try this [[[[DictJsonName objectForKey:@"wk_time"] objectForKey:@"user"] objectAtIndex:changeNumber] objectForKey:@"name"] for test yourself  on taking breakpoint n test in debug area started by po

Comment: @RamVinayYadav  bro this is my response {
  "projects": [
    {
      "id": 8,
      "name": "Andriod APP",
      "identifier": "andriod-app",
      "description": "",
      "status": 1,
      "is_public": true,
      "created_on": "2015-06-29T11:54:23Z",
      "updated_on": "2015-06-29T11:54:23Z"
    },
    ],
  "total_count": 8,
  "offset": 0,
  "limit": 25
}   how to get the project id

Comment: @RamVinayYadav  bro if i put like this                                               self.data = [jsonObjects  objectForKey:@"projects”];


NSDictionary * tmpdict = [self.data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


cell.textLabel.text = [tmpdict objectForKey:@"name" ]; i will get the project name but similarly i can't get the  project id ..how to get the project id value..

Comment: @catherine007 Use it : cell.textLabel.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[tmpdict objectForKey:@"id" ]];    Because your id is not data type of string so first convert it into string . For more contact me on Skype ramvinay093@gmail.com .

Comment: @hi bro i have one more doubt i will send my sample project please take a look and clarify me bro...

Comment: i skyped you and i send my demo project ....to you bro..

Comment: @RamVinayYadav bro i am s.boopathi i skyped you and send my demo project to your mail id..i wish to need clarification on this coding.

Comment: {
 "projects": [
    {
      "id": 8,
      "name": "Andriod APP",
      "identifier": "andriod-app",
      "description": "",
      "status": 1,
      "is_public": true,
      "created_on": "2015-06-29T11:54:23Z",
      "updated_on": "2015-06-29T11:54:23Z"
    },
    ],
  "total_count": 8,
  "offset": 0,
  "limit": 25
}   my projects json response

Comment: {
"issues":[
{
"id": 22,
"project": {
"id": 4,
"name": "Vitals"
 },
"tracker":{
 "id": 3,
 "name": "Support"
},
"status": {
"id": 1,
"name": "New"
},
"priority": {
"id": 2,
"name": "Normal"
 },
"author": {
"id": 1,
"name": "Redmine Admin"
 },
"subject": "Lead page creation",
"description": "",
"start_date": "2015-06-25",
"done_ratio": 0,
"created_on": "2015-06-25T10:22:22Z",
"updated_on": "2015-06-25T10:22:22Z"
}
],
"total_count": 17,
"offset": 0,
"limit": 25
} this is my issues response

Comment: NSURLRequest * urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.0.8/redmine/projects.json"]];
NSError * error = nil;
NSURLResponse * response = nil;
NSData * jsonSource = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest returningResponse:&response error:&error];
id jsonObjects = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonSource options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
if ([jsonObjects objectForKey:@"projects"] != [NSNull null]) {
self.data = [jsonObjects  objectForKey:@"projects"];
NSLog(@" %@",self.data);
} this is my piece of code

Comment: NSURLRequest * urlRequest1 = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.0.8/redmine/issues.json"]];
NSError * error1 = nil;
NSURLResponse * response1 = nil;
NSData * jsonSource1 = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest1 returningResponse:&response1 error:&error1]
id jsonObjects1 = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonSource1 options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
if ([jsonObjects1 objectForKey:@"issues"] != [NSNull null]) {
self.data1 = [jsonObjects1 objectForKey:@"issues"];
NSLog(@" %@",self.data1);
}

Comment: - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
NSDictionary * tmpdict = [self.data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSLog(@ " %@",tmpdict);
NSDictionary * tmpdict2 = [self.data1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSLog(@ " %@",tmpdict2);
if (cell == nil) {
cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
}

Comment: if(tableView == self.tableView){
cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
cell.textLabel.text = [tmpdict objectForKey:@"name"];
NSLog(@ " %@",cell.textLabel.text);
}
else if(tableView == self.tableView1) {
//cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
cell.textLabel.text = [tmpdict2 objectForKey:@"subject"];
NSLog(@ " %@",cell.textLabel.text);
}
// cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
return cell;
}

Comment: on this i get the values from my dictionary are dynamic ...i get the drop downs like this  http://i.imgur.com/DsCtoD7.png  but on scrolling issues drop down it shows error like NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 8 beyond bounds [0 .. 7]'   how to rectify it bro....

Comment: @RamVinayYadav bro [[[[[DictJsonName objectForKey:@"wk_time"] objectForKey:@"time_entries"] objectAtIndex:changeNumber] objectForKey:@"project"] objectForKey:@"name"] [[[[[DictJsonName objectForKey:@"wk_time"] objectForKey:@"time_entries"] objectAtIndex:changeNumber] objectForKey:@"activity"] objectForKey:@"name"] we can change the object at index dynamically if we give object at index:0 means it shows vitals,22,design only but it having more than 10 set of values...i wish to get all the projects,issues,activity values. how to get this any other options..help me bro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &err];

NSDictionary *dictUser = [[jsonDict objectForKey:@"wk_time"]objectForKey:@"user"];

NSArray *array = [[jsonDict objectForKey:@"wk_time"]objectAtIndex:0];

for(int i=0;i<[array count];i++)
{

    NSDictionary *dictTimeEntries = [[array objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"time_entries"];

    NSDictionary *dictProject = [dictTimeEntries objectForKey:@"project"];

    NSString *stringProjectName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dictProject valueForKey@"name"]];

    NSLog(@"The stringProjectName is - %@",stringProjectName);

    NSString *stingProjectID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dictProject valueForKey@"id"]];

    NSLog(@"The stringProjectID is - %@",stingProjectID);


    NSDictionary *dictActivity = [dictTimeEntries objectForKey:@"activity"];

    NSString *stringActivityName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dictActivity valueForKey@"name"]];

    NSLog(@"The stringActivityName is - %@",stringActivityName);

    NSString *stingActivityID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dictActivity valueForKey@"id"]];

    NSLog(@"The stingActivityID is - %@",stingActivityID);

}
```

Comment: yeah thanks bro...could u give your mail id ...i will send my sample project i have some doubts..could you clarify me...

Comment: Do you want my personal id?

Comment: Why did you un tick my answer?

Comment: could you give your id bro?

Comment: tell me your mail id.I will send you the text mail.

Comment: katrinetheressa@gmail.com

Comment: I sent the test mail to your mail id.Check it

Comment: Me too got your reply

Comment: NSString *stingProjectID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dictProject valueForKey@"id"]]; bro on this line it shows the error expected ']' how to resolve it.

Comment: Okey send me.I il check

Comment: I replied you,please check it.

Comment: I think you missed to add ']' at the end of the string.

Comment: I sent the mail please check it.

Comment: bro on this code it shows the error at objectatindex..how to solve  this.

Comment: [__NSDictionaryM objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe969c6e850'

Comment: 2015-12-14 20:23:14.518 testapi[3941:46772] -[__NSDictionaryM objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe969c6e850

2015-12-14 20:23:14.585 testapi[3941:46772] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDictionaryM objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe969c6e850'

Comment: NSArray *array = [[jsonDict objectForKey:@"wk_time"]objectAtIndex:0]; on this line it shows the error

Comment: Please send me your source code.I have to check that.

Comment: NSURLRequest * urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"my url "]];
NSError * error = nil;
NSURLResponse * response = nil;
NSData * jsonSource = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequestreturningResponsereturningResponse:&response
error:&error];
NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonSource options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &error];
NSLog(@" %@", jsonDict);
NSDictionary *dictUser = [[jsonDict objectForKey:@"wk_time"]objectForKey:@"time_entries"];
NSLog(@" %@", dictUser);

Comment: it works upto this  after that ..NSArray * array = [[jsonDict objectForKey:@"wk_time"]  objectAtIndex:0] ;
NSLog(@" %@", array);
for(int i=0;i<[array count];i++)
{
 NSDictionary *dictTimeEntries = [[array objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"time_entries"];
NSDictionary *dictProject = [dictTimeEntries objectForKey:@"project"];
NSString *stringProjectName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dictProject valueForKey:@"name"]];
NSLog(@"The stringProjectName is - %@",stringProjectName
}
} it won't goes inside this loop or nsarray * array it shows error on object atindex:0we have to use mutable array

Comment: yeah bro u alreay having my source code in the project name rest api and u rectified some syntax..

Comment: If i get the response that is very useful for me

Comment: That's why i am asking

Comment: http://192.168.0.8/redmine/wktime/edit.json?startday=2015-08-09&user_id=11&key=828ea7fa548b09098f2acd6c9334411c7a2cdac4

Comment: show me your full response as the url has not worked.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend that you translate the JSON result to object. A very useful and easy to start library to do so - https://github.com/icanzilb/JSONModel

This way you can create a class that represents the response and easily access all the properties like normal i.e. `user.name`